# Filtering 2 columns for matching values

Tags: excel, filter, formula

I have 2 columns in excel. I want to find matching values within these two columns and put them in a third column.

Here’s what I tried:

```
=FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,B:B))
```

returns 0

Sample data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| AA01 | EE04 |
| CC02 | CD06 |
| BB03 | AA02 |
| AA04 | AA01 |
| EE04 | CC02 |

Expected output:

| C |
| --- |
| AA01 |
| CC02 |
| EE04 |

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as the expected outcomes, you will then more likely get a quick and useful response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `XMATCH()` or `COUNTIF()`

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A1:A5,B1:B5)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `E1`

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,COUNTIF(B1:B5,A1:A5))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH` to find if value in `A` cell is in `B` column.

If you have Excel 365 you can use formula in `C1`:

```
=FILTER(BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(row,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(row,$B$1:$B$5,0)),"",row))),BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(row,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(row,$B$1:$B$5,0)),"",row)))<>"","")
```

Result:
[image]

Otherwise use `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$5,0)),"",A1)` in `C1` dragged down, `FILTER` result in `D1` with `=FILTER(C1:C5,C1:C5<>"")`:

[image]